# Synonym for "for the time being"

Tags: phrase-request, email

I'm writing an email and I want to ask them (Career Development Office) if there are any volunteering opportunities for the time being.

But, the way I wrote it in the actual message doesn't really match with saying "for the time being". I'm looking to say that in a more proper and formal way.

The meaning I want to go for is something along the lines of "temporarily" or "for this period" or "currently".

Are there any suggestions?

---

For the time being = a bit informal

Temporarily = sounds as if you are not serious enough and only looking to volunteer for an hour and then give up

Momentarily = ? sounds like you couldn't come up with a better wording

For the moment = for just ONE MOMENT ???

---

seems like I cannot come up with the word to describe in a literal and formal, at the same time, way what I am looking for.

I want to say something along the lines of:
**I am available now, and in the near future, but after that, not anymore.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using more than one sentence. You want to convey information about your availability, and you also want to inquire whether there are opportunities to volunteer.
"Are there any opportunities to volunteer **at this time**?"
"I am available for/during/until etc."

Comment: Thank you. I ended up going for: "at the moment".